# vba code : if the number of rows are =1 then display a message box and stop the macro else continue the macro

Tags: vba, excel

i need a vba code for the following. Will be glad if you can help.vba code : if 
the number of rows are =1 (only for the visible cells) then display a message box and stop the macro else continue the macro.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?  This is very easy to do

Answer (score 0):

```
If Sheets(1).AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count = 1 Then
  MsgBox "number of rows = 1"
  End sub
End If
```

edit this code to meet your needs

Answer (score 0):

I have used xlCellTypeVisible to count the rows.

Sub test1()

```
Dim Lastrow As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet


Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Lastrow = ws.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count


If Lastrow = 1 Then

     MsgBox " Rows les than 1"
    Exit Sub
Else

End If




End Sub
```